# Go multistage docker build fails with standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, go

I've followed several articles and examples including the one from the official Docker example for multi-stage builds.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM golang:1.16-buster AS builder
WORKDIR /src
COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY *.go ./
COPY dev.env ./
RUN go build

# exec stage
FROM alpine:3.15
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /src/tendies-cli /app/
ENTRYPOINT [ "./tendies-cli" ]
CMD [ "reset", "refill" ]
```

Every time I docker run it returns

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

But even when I run it in interactive shell mode using `docker run -it cli /bin/sh` I can see that the executable is there. I'm a docker newbie so any advice would be great.

I'm running on MacOS Big Sur and Docker Engine 20.10.11 CE

Comment: At entrypoint, try complete path "/app/tendies-cli"

Answer (score 0):

Try build with this command

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags="-w -s"
```

I faced this problem too when trying to build a minimalist docker image and run it on docker scratch

source: https://chemidy.medium.com/create-the-smallest-and-secured-golang-docker-image-based-on-scratch-4752223b7324

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).